# Some inline plots won't print from Ipython noteboook

Tags: matplotlib, ipython

I am using Ipython Notebook to generate some bar plots. 
The code cell is this:

```
kcount =0;for k, v in pledge.groupby(['Date','Break']).sum().Amount.iteritems():
if k[0] <> kcount:
    kcount=k[0]
    pledge[pledge.Date==k[0]].groupby(['Break','Progcode'])['Amount'].sum().plot(kind='bar')
    plt.title(k[0])
    plt.figure()
```

This gives me a bar plot for every day of our pledge drive, showing how each show within that day did. 24 charts in all. They display great as output on the screen, but when I use the Print button in Ipython Notebook, it only prints enough graphs to fill the last page, which can vary from 3 to 6 graphs depending on the printer used. One printer used reported that it required 11x17 paper for the print job (not something I set anywhere) and when I manually set it for 8 1/2 x 11, it again only printed out the first 3 pages.  I am at a loss as to what to do at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up saving these pages to a multipage PDF file and then printing them from there. 
 Consult the docs http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_pdf_api.html

To see how to save several figures to a multipage PDF file.

This also looks like a good resource. http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=94

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, can you can use `plt.savefig('filename.png')` (or .jpg, or .whatever) to save an image file and then print the files out manually?

Comment: Yes that is a workaround that I am considering, but then I have to print over 20 files manually, which I would rather not do.